# How to keep stage DB always up to date?

Tags: database, postgresql, infrastructure

I have a task and I don't know which solution will be "more correct" .. could you help me with advice?

We have a PostgreSQL production database and we need to make a stage database in which it is possible to carry out operations of reading and writing.
And here's the question: how to keep the stage database always up to date?
So far, I see the following options:

- *physical replication master-slave* - there is no possibility to write in a DB.
- *logical replication* - when adding new tables or columns we get replication errors.
- *triggers* - not sure if this is the right and reliable option.

Maybe there are some best practices for such task?

Comment: Does it need to have the same data, or just the same schema?

Comment: @Matthew, yes, I need the same data.